# Adding spring-boot-starter-security to Spring Boot application causes error 'entityManagerFactory' or 'persistenceUnitName' is required

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-orm

I created a Spring Boot (0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) application using Spring Initializr (http://start.spring.io/), and I added a single @RestController, a single CrudRepository interface, and a single @Entity class - nothing complicated.  My Maven POM contains the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The Application class contains the default:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The simple application runs without errors, but I decided to add Spring Security to the POM to secure the management endpoints:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Now the application won't start, and I get the following:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'entityManagerFactory' or 'persistenceUnitName' is required**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'entityManagerFactory' or 'persistenceUnitName' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JpaTransactionManager.java:304)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.<init>(JpaTransactionManager.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.transactionManager(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 18 more
```

When I remove the spring-boot-starter-security dependency, the application runs fine but without security enabled.  What does the error mean? The application already uses JPA and Hibernate without Spring Security enabled.

Comment: It looks like maybe some beans in the security config are forcing early instantiation of some JPA dependencies. I never saw this specific problem before though, and we have worked on quite a few apps with JPA and Security. There might be an odd ordering problem that we never saw before. I'll have a look and see if I can reproduce it. Anyone else with an answer feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [bug there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/151). The cause is really deeply technical and related to the internals in a Spring `BeanFactory`. Look at the Github issue if you want to get some more understanding, but probably you should be able to just refresh your snapshot dependencies and get the fix.